# Getting the earliest date from the date column to show when grouping another column

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have the following table:

| item_name | trade_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chair | 1 | 01-01-2021 |
| chair | 2 | 02-01-2021 |
| desk | 3 | 02-01-2021 |
| chair | 4 | 03-01-2021 |
| table | 5 | 03-01-2021 |

I'm trying to group the rows in the table by `item_name` while also displaying the `date` of the first/earliest `trade_id` (in other words, my desired output is along the lines of `| chair | 1, 2, 4 | 01-01-2021 |`, while the current output is `| chair | 1, 2, 4 | 03-01-2021 |`), but had no luck (only found possible solutions using `ORDER BY`, which sadly didn't work).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` along with `MIN`:

```sql
SELECT item_name, GROUP_CONCAT(trade_id ORDER BY trade_id), MIN(date) AS first_date
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY item_name;
```